# Split postgres connections between web and worker dynos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm using two hobby dev dynos, one web, one worker - with a hobby basic postgres.  I think I used up my (20) postgres connections with the worker, I was wondering how many connections should be allocated for each?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how many 'processes' your running of your web and worker dynos.

If you're running one web process, and one worker process, and each has 10 connections in the connection pool, you'd then be using your full allocation of connections (20). This would likely be the most optimal split.

Comment: Thanks man, do you know how to specify 10 each?  I see in database.yml pool: 20, but I'm not sure the correct way to split it.

Comment: nevermind, found it here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/forked-pg-connections#forked-environments